# Jest not able to verify presence for a proeprty using toHaveProperty

Tags: javascript, enzyme, jestjs

I am using Jest and enzyme, I have a react component, below its structure when performing `.debug()`.

```
 console.log src\shared\navigation\Navigations.test.js:20
    <NavLink to="/" exact={true} activeStyle={{...}} activeClassName="active">
      Weather
    </NavLink>
```

I am using the following code to try to test if `NavLink` has a property `to` with value `/`.

The property is not found (I believe when the component is mounted using shallow the object is decorated with other properties [code below]).

I need to know how to test the property like would be returned by the `debug()` function.

```js
  it('shouldhave property home', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <Navigations />
    )
    const test = wrapper.find(NavLink).first()
    console.log(test.debug())
    expect(test).toHaveProperty('to', '/')
  })
```

---

Object version returned by the test case:

```js
  {"complexSelector": {"buildPredicate": [Function buildPredicate], "childrenOfNode": [Function childrenOfNode], "findWhereUnwrapped": [Function findWhereUnwrapped]}, "length": 1, "node": <NavLink activeClassName="active" activeStyle={{"color": "red", "fontWeight": "bold"}} exact={true} to="/">Weather</NavLink>, "nodes": [<NavLink activeClassName="active" activeStyle={{"color": "red", "fontWeight": "bold"}} exact={true} to="/">Weather</NavLink>], "options": {}, "renderer": null, "root": {"complexSelector": {"buildPredicate": [Function buildPredicate], "childrenOfNode": [Function childrenOfNode], "findWhereUnwrapped": [Function findWhereUnwrapped]}, "length": 1, "node": <div><withStyles(Drawer) classes={{"paper": "Navigations-drawerPaper-1"}} type="permanent"><div className="Navigations-drawerInner-3"><div … /><withStyles(Divider) … /><withStyles(ListItem) … /><withStyles(ListItem) … /></div></withStyles(Drawer)></div>, "nodes": [<div><withStyles(Drawer) classes={[Object]} type="permanent"><div … /></withStyles(Drawer)></div>], "options": {}, "renderer": {"_instance": {"_calledComponentWillUnmount": false, "_compositeType": 0, "_context": {}, "_currentElement": <withStyles(Navigations) />, "_debugID": 3, "_hostContainerInfo": null, "_hostParent": null, "_instance": {"_reactInternalInstance": [Circular], "context": [Object], "jss": [Jss], "props": [Object], "refs": [Object], "sheetOptions": [Object], "sheetsManager": [Map], "state": [Object], "stylesCreatorSaved": [Object], "theme": [Object], "unsubscribeId": null, "updater": [Object]}, "_mountOrder": 2, "_pendingCallbacks": null, "_pendingElement": null, "_pendingForceUpdate": false, "_pendingReplaceState": false, "_pendingStateQueue": null, "_renderedComponent": {"_currentElement": <div … />, "_debugID": 4, "_renderedOutput": <div … />}, "_renderedNodeType": 0, "_rootNodeID": 0, "_topLevelWrapper": null, "_updateBatchNumber": null, "_warnedAboutRefsInRender": false}, "getRenderOutput": [Function getRenderOutput], "render": [Function render]}, "root": [Circular], "unrendered": <withStyles(Navigations) />}, "unrendered": null}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use `.get()` (or `.first()` in the second example) to take a specific element from the array returned by `.find()` and use `.props` to check for a property or passing and object to search directly in `.find()`.

Docs:

http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ReactWrapper/get.html 
http://airbnb.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html

```js
  it('should have property home', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<Navigations />)
    expect(wrapper.find(NavLink).get(0).props.to).toEqual('/')
  })
```

or

```js
      it('should have property home', () => {
        const wrapper = shallow(<Navigations />)
        expect(wrapper.find(NavLink).find({ to: '/' }).first().length === 1).toEqual(true)
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a race condition, where the test is checking it before `NavLink` has the property. For more info, look at Jest's documentation on [testing asynchronous code](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/asynchronous.html#content)

```
it('shouldhave property home', (done) => {
  const wrapper = shallow(
    <Navigations />,
  );
  const test = wrapper.find(NavLink).first();
  console.log(test.debug());
  expect(test).toHaveProperty('to', '/');
  done();
});
```

Comment: @Jason, I do not think it is a race condition, the property `to` it is actually there as the OP mention in his question. You can see the property in this beautified version https://jsfiddle.net/wL8fg0Lh/

Comment: To debug the issue, do `console.log(test)` and see what that is. Then, add an explicit wait for 10 seconds and then do another `console.log(test)` and see if anything has changed. If something has changed then you know you have a race condition.