# React Native and Enzyme assertion error: Object not matching nested property

Tags: javascript, testing, react-native, enzyme

I am new to react native, enzyme and jest. I am trying to get a simple test working, to test child nodes. (Perhaps this is an incorrect way of trying to do so).

My Component is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class MyComponent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
}

render() {
  return (
    <View >
      <Button title="My Component"/>
    </View>
  )
}
}
export default MyComponent;
```

and my test is

```
import React from 'react';
import { configure, shallow } from 'enzyme';
import Adapter from 'enzyme-adapter-react-16';
import MyComponent from '../components/MyComponent.js';

configure({ adapter: new Adapter() })  //setting up enzyme

const styles = require('../styles.js');

describe('rendering', () => {  
  it('checking View and Button exists', () => {
    let wrapper
    wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent/>); 

    expect(wrapper.find('View').children().find('Button')).toHaveProperty('title','My Component')
    });
    })
});
```

I am getting an error that the object return is not matching the expected:

```
Expected the object:
 < listing of full object...>
To have a nested property:
  "title"
With a value of:
  "My Component"
```

The object returned shows MyComponent as a child of the root View, as well as the prop, but it is failing. Should I be doing this differently? I want to be able to create a test structure that will eventually confirm a number of child components and props under the View Component.
(as a side note, I would prefer to use Mocha, but I am coming up against [this error](https://github.com/react-native-material-design/react-native-material-design/issues/103) which I haven't been able to resolve.

Comment: In the meantime, I am using snapshot to test -- perhaps that is the only way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

This other question helped me to answer my problem
https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546619/4797507 (apologies if I am not giving credit correctly)

The solution was for me to use:

`expect(wrapper.find('View').children().find('Button').get(0).props.title).toEqual('My Component')`